# Is there any English translation of the Gergonne paper "Variétés. Essai de dialectique rationnelle" ("Varieties. Essay about rational dialectic")?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, reference-request, math-history, reference-works

Is there any English translation of this Gergonne paper?

"Variétés. Essai de dialectique rationnelle", Annales de Mathématiques pures et appliquées, tome 7 (1816-1817), p. 189-228.

("Varieties. Essay about rational dialectic", By J.D. Gergonne).
Between else, in this paper we find the first use of the symbols "C" and "Ɔ", which later evolved into the modern symbols "$\subset$" and "$\supset$", used in set theory and, in older texts, for implication.

You can find it [here (PDF link via numdam.org)](http://www.numdam.org/article/AMPA_1816-1817__7__189_0.pdf), in French.

If there isn't any, I believe it deserves one. I would certainly do it, if I could.

---

This question has also been posted on [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13146/is-there-any-english-translation-of-this-gergonne-paper).

Comment: Maybe an interim solution would be to use DeepL.

Comment: @user7427029 Is this better than Google? Google translation is readable, but with errors.

Comment: It uses a deep neural network and is rather good. I have achieved good results with newspaper articles, but did not test it with mathematical papers.

Comment: I'd be curious to see an AI trying this one. It would be amazing if the result was any good though. This is old-fashioned French, not so old as to be archaic, but still. And the topic is quite exotic for the type of AIs I expect to see on the market. I can't imagine seeing replicated the pompous and slightly patronizing style of the introduction, which is mostly philosophical and not really mathematical. You would need a native speaker (in the target language, English), who knows enough of maths and philosophy, and can perceive the nuances of fairly old French. Can't say I'm optimistic.

Comment: It might be worth asking your question on https://hsm.stackexchange.com.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will.

Comment: @user3733558 just commenting to let you know that the paper has been translated! (see answer below)

Answer (score 3):

Sam Gallagher translated the paper after this question was post. So, now there is a translation! You can find his work [here](https://histomathsci.blogspot.com/2021/05/translation-of-j-d-gergonnes-varities.html).